# How to manage a large mail archive?

Tags: software-recommendation, mail

I have a few gigabyte of old mail, mostly unsorted as nnml format (i.e. Gnus, with one file per mail). How can I turn that mail into something useful, i.e. something I can search and browse easily and fast (i.e. `grep` takes far to long). I have no need for a full mail client, just the archive management part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the [Notmuch](http://notmuchmail.org/) mail indexer library.  It is designed so that it can be used as a backing store for some mail client, but can also be used as independent mail index.

It maintains a [Xapian](http://xapian.org/) full text index of your mail, so search queries should be a lot more efficient than `grep` once you have all the messages imported.